# How to set up an activity to extent under the navigation bar, but not under the statusbar?

Tags: android, android-theme, crosswalk-runtime

Using the following theme file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#f8a278</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#ffc27d61</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
</style>
```

I get a neat looking statusbar, but I lose the transparent navigation bar. Removing the `fitsSystemWindows` gives me the transparent navigation bar, but my application ends up hiding behind the statusbar. How should I set up my theme file for the navigation bar to show transparently, whilst the statusbar simply uses the `colorPrimaryDark` color?

---

Note: I am using crosswalk to generate my application. This means I am slightly limited in what I can and can not do. Ideally I would like to get this configured purely from the theme files and `AndroidManifest.xml`, without having to change the code, though I won't complain if this really is not possible.